# Seeing numbers in float format in Pycharm Debugger instead of scientific format

Tags: debugging, pycharm, floating-point

It is extremely uncomfortable to see small numbers in scientific format, can I force PyCharm debugger show the numbers in float, e.g. `0.01` instead of `1e-02` or `101` instead of `1.01e+02`?
Thanks!

As I work with PyTorch, I tried `torch.set_printoptions(precision=5)`, but it looks it does not work in debugger.

Comment: You might want to edit the title to correct the terminology. Scientific notation is 1×10^−2 (where ^ denotes a superscript, for which the typography is not available in comments). “0.01” and “101” are not scientific notation. “1e-02” and “1.01e+02” are effectively scientific notation, since they are equivalent to 1×10^−02 and 1.10×10^+02 except for the typography. It seems like you are asking for some fixed-point notation, not scientific notation.